# how do i fix bool and int not iterable error in my function?

Tags: python

The purpose of the function is to make a new list base on the inputted list. If original list has a string, make it upper case. If has Boolean, make it opposite. If has a list inside the list, make it 'List', if has int or float, +1.

Here is my function:

```
def afunc(alist):
    i = 0
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        if type(alist[i]) == str:
            new_list += alist[i].upper()
        elif type(alist[i]) == bool:
            new_list += not alist[i]
        elif type(alist[i]) == list:
            new_list += 'List'
        else:
            new_list += 1  
    return new_list
```

Comment: `new_list` is not defined.

Comment: semi-related, why are you using a loop with an "index"? Your only usage of `i` seems to be to access the current list item. Simply doing `for item in alist:` is preferable in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'+' joins two lists and since int and bool is not iterable, it displays error.

Use append to add items to the list.

```
def afunc(alist):
    i = 0
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(alist)):
         if type(alist[i]) == str:
          new_list.append(alist[i].upper())
         elif type(alist[i]) == bool:
             new_list.append(not alist[i])
         elif type(alist[i]) == list:
             new_list.append('List')
         else:
             new_list.append(1) 
    return new_list
```